# In Postgres, when using LTREE, can the ID column be gotten rid of since the `LTREE` path has the ID already as the last label?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, ltree

Let's say I have a `ID TEXT PRIMARY KEY` column and this `ID` is used to create the `PATH LTREE` column for the row when inserting data. So the `ID` ends up as the last label in the path.

So, is it a wise idea to get rid of the ID column all-together since the `LTREE` path has the ID already as the last label?

Can the `PATH LTREE` be made the primary key?

Is there any harm in this approach?

Comment: If you're still using PostgreSQL 9.1, you should probably consider upgrading (if you can). It's EoL was October 27, 2016.

Comment: Every table needs a primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [example in the `ltree` module documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html#id-1.11.7.32.8):

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (path ltree);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Science');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Science.Astronomy');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Science.Astronomy.Astrophysics');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Science.Astronomy.Cosmology');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Hobbies');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Hobbies.Amateurs_Astronomy');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Collections');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Collections.Pictures');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Stars');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Galaxies');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy.Astronauts');
CREATE INDEX path_gist_idx ON test USING GIST (path);
CREATE INDEX path_idx ON test USING BTREE (path);
```

You can see there are two entries with "Astronomy" as leaf value.

If your ID is always used as the last label, it may be have duplicates in this case (so no longer has the primary key constraints).

You might be able to replicate the uniqueness constraint using a unique index on the last label:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON test (subpath(test.path, -1, 1));
```

However, you won't be able to create a primary key from this index because it depends on an expression.

I guess it all depends on how you maintain the consistency between your ID and the ltree value.

It's probably be worth keeping the `ID` column as a primary key and compute its value automatically (e.g. via trigger) using `subpath(..., -1, 1)`  whenever your `ltree` value is inserted and updated, or at least have some form of constraint to make sure it's consistent with the path.

It also depends on what you would do regarding [row locks](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/row-locks-in-postgresql/).

In particular, [a unique index on `subpath(test.path, -1, 1)` would not fully replicate the behaviour of a Primary Key index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS):

> *Currently, the set of columns considered for the UPDATE case are those that have a unique index on them that can be used in a foreign key (**so partial indexes and expressional indexes are not considered**), but this may change in the future.*

Comment: In the example, there are 2 entries with "Astronomy" as leaf value. However, isn't the entire path considered for uniqueness if I made it the primary key? The `'Top.Science.Astronomy'` and `'Top.Hobbies.Amateurs_Astronomy'` are still unique no?

Comment: They would yes, but your question is about using `ID TEXT PRIMARY KEY` where ID is also the last label in your other `LTREE` column, isn't it? It itself, if you just use the `LTREE` column directly, you'd lose that constraint on the last label.

Comment: Sorry, I was asking about whether I can remove the `ID TEXT PRIMARY KEY` column entirely and replace with `PATH LTREE PRIMARY KEY`. And when inserting, I insert into the calculated `PATH` instead. That would make it unique right?

Comment: You can have `path LTREE PRIMARY KEY`, but that doesn't have the same meaning as `ID TEXT PRIMARY KEY`. If you had `ID TEXT PRIMARY KEY` and if your ID is also the last label of every path, then you can't have two `Top.Science.Astronomy` and `Top.Collections.Pictures.Astronomy` (if `Astronomy` is the value of ID in both cases). If you use `path LTREE PRIMARY KEY`, then you can. It doesn't have the same meaning, so it depends on the constraints you want to have on your data. By using the PK on `path LTREE` column this way, you're effectively slightly relaxing your constraint on ID.